# .NET Core 3.1 loading config from appsettings.json for console application

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, console, .net-core-3.1

For .NET Core 3.1, console application how can I read a complex object from appsetting.json file and cast it into the corresponding object?

All the examples I see online seem to be for previous versions of .NET core and things seems to have changed since then. Below is my sample code. I don't really know how to proceed from here. Thank you for your help.

appsettings.json

```
{
  "Player": {
    "Name": "Messi",
    "Age": "31",
    "Hobby": "Football"
  }
}
```

Player.cs

```cs
class Player
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string Hobby { get; set; }
}
```

Program.cs

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()?.Location))
        .AddJsonFile("appsetting.json").Build();
    var playerSection = config.GetSection("Player");
}
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In .Net Core 3.1 you need to install these packages:

- `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json`
- `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions`

then build `IConfiguration`:

```cs
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
    IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
       .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true,true)
       .Build();
    var playerSection = configuration.GetSection(nameof(Player));
}
```

Reference [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration)

Comment: Ah yes, nice. This gave me what I wanted. Thank you! 



```
 IConfigurationSection playerSection = configuration.GetSection(nameof(Player));
            var name = playerSection["Name"];
```

Comment: @stuck_inside_task Glad I could help you :) Good luck

Comment: For info adding Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json via nuget will also add Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions

Comment: Also worth mentioning you should set `Copy to Output Directory=Copy always` for your newly added appsettings.json file.

Comment: What if I need to read a settings json file from a .NET 3.1 class library assembly (dll), can I use this mechanism, since there is no "Main" entry point in the assembly?